# pressing CTRL +C to EXIT to exit the python program

Tags: python, exit

Trying to write a code that exits on a pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> anywhere in the code had problems implementing because most of online help refer to signalling and other stuff
this might not be related to what am asking for. Can skip this part and provide a solution

```
import signal
import time

def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Stop pressing the CTRL+C!'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
```

**Objective:**

> Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> should just quit the program

Comment: so what? what's the question?

Comment: CTRL+C selnds SIGTERM. Maybe you could catch that instead? Not sure exactly what the question is though...

Comment: ...or catch `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: but sends me back importing signal and all the code that follows ,but still not exiting on CTRL + C ,any sample code or links for exactly just exiting using CTRL +C

Comment: So the question is that you want the script to only EVER quit when CTRL+C is hit? That's default behavior for the script to stop when CTRL+C is hit. If you want to do something before that happens, you will catch the SIGTERM and then do something. When it's complete, the program exits back to console or whatever.

Comment: import signal
import sys

def handler(signum, frame):
        res = input("Do you want to exit?[y/N]")
        if res == 'y':
                sys.exit()


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)


count = 0
while True:
        print(count)
        count+=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either do a try/except on a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
try:
  while True:
    print 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "test"
```

Alternatively, if the process itself is killed, you will get a `SIGTERM` sent by the KILL command:

As you indicated, you can define a handler: `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, my_signal_term_handler)`

Here are a list of all the UNIX signals to consider : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals. Note that SIGKILL cannot be caught.